# Is the Facebook 'Discussion' widget available to the public?

Tags: facebook, xfbml

Going over the [XFBML Comments widget](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/), i've noticed that right below their example sits a much better widget, titled **Discussion**.

I didn't find documentation about it anywhere. Does anyone know if and how one could use such widget on his website?

**Update:** Just found [a comment](http://www.allfacebook.com/facebook-dramatically-upgrades-comments-plugin-features-2010-10#IDComment104048897) which states it's a feedback plugin which is used only by Facebook internally. This still doesn't say if it's going to be available, when and how to get it.

Comment: They will allowed public use. Not now but later. ;)